# Перезагрузка модуля Ymaps Яндекс

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть ли способ повторно загрузить модуль Ymaps, не перезагружая страницу? Если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: Эм.. Но зачем??

Comment: нужно изменять радиус круга тепловой карты. 
я вроде как нашел решение через `ymaps.modules.require`